# How do I filter out values from these JSON objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm using a online API that returns to me JSON code and I don't know how to filter out the "name" value in the JSON code. The JSON that I'm trying to filter is in many objects and I've tried many different ways. How do I get the values of "name" out of each object? I've tried to do .people.name but I always get a blank output or it would just say "[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]"

JSON response:

```
{
  "message": "success",
  "number": 6,
  "people": [
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Oleg Kononenko"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "David Saint-Jacques"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Anne McClain"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Alexey Ovchinin"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Nick Hague"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Christina Koch"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code in NodeJS:

```js
request('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', (error, response, html) => {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            let astroJSON = JSON.parse(html);

            let astroNum = astroJSON.number;
            let astroNames = JSON.stringify(astroJSON.people); // This is what I need help with!
            console.log("Number: " + astroNum);
            console.log("Crew names: " + astroNames); // Return the JSON response that I sent above. 
        }
    });
```

Comment: `people` is an array. So  `.people.name` won't work.

Comment: Can do `JSON.stringify(astroJSON.people, null, 2)` but why are you doing `JSON.stringify`, just output it, without appending a string to the front.

Comment: @TheREE just for reference you are not working with JSON. You have already parsed the JSON and the result is a javascript object. You dont filter JSON. You dont interact with JSON at all, ever. You parse it or send/store it. Nothing more or less.

Comment: Additionally you dont need to serialize your people collection. You can just pass the object to console.log as another parameter. `consoile.log("Crew Names: ", astroJSON.people)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Array#prototype#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = `{
  "message": "success",
  "number": 6,
  "people": [
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Oleg Kononenko"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "David Saint-Jacques"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Anne McClain"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Alexey Ovchinin"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Nick Hague"
    },
    {
      "craft": "ISS",
      "name": "Christina Koch"
    }
  ]
}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(data);

const astroNames = obj.number;

// Join the crew names with a comma
const crew = obj.people.map(x => x.name).join(', ');
console.log(crew);
```

**Change your code to this:**

```
request('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', (error, response, html) => {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            let astroJSON = JSON.parse(html);

            let astroNum = astroJSON.number;
            let astroNames = astroJSON.people.map(x => x.name).join(', ');
            console.log("Number: " + astroNum);
            console.log("Crew names: " + astroNames); // Return the JSON response that I sent above. 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how can I now remove the " , and [ ] in the output so that It can look nicer for the user? Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You must map over the array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

e.g.

```
astroJSON.people.map(person => person.name)
```

Will log an array of the names of the people:

```
["Oleg Kononenko", "David Saint-Jacques", "Anne McClain", "Alexey Ovchinin", "Nick Hague", "Christina Koch"]
```

In order to remove the brackets and the comas you can use

```
astroNames.join(' ')
```

which returns the string `"Oleg Kononenko David Saint-Jacques Anne McClain Alexey Ovchinin Nick Hague Christina Koch"`

See [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)